# iMacros doesn't recognize facebook comment textbox

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, imacros

I've been trying to automate a process of replying to comments on facebook. I have iMacros click on the "Reply" button successfully, but when it comes to the comment reply itself or uploading a photo in the comment, it doesn't recognize the tag at all. I actually have to manually click on the comment or photo button once and cancel it, in order for facebook to change the html state of the input to something imacros sees. I don't know why this is happening.

I've tried conventional recording mode without using ID selectors, i've also tried conventional recording with complete HTML tag, but the main issue is that it just doesn't see that comment section.

I know how to code in javascript and imacros, so if a JavaScript solution is out there then that would help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using experimental recording and event command. And uncheck the "Favor elemens ID in selectors" . Also when you use complete HTML tag remove the unnecessary stuff.

Facebook has random HTML tags like IDs so that will "confuse" scripts.

If that fails then try with http://wiki.imacros.net/XPATH .

Answer (score 1):

i did a little check on this manner and i came up with some good results.
the following imacro code will reply on the comment and add a pic too.
all you have to do is replace the "C:\1.jpg" on the line 16 of the code with you image location and edit the text "nice" on the line 23 with your own text and you can use csv files for comments and i can guide you through that if you want.
i tried this and its worked perfectly just get a post where comment replies are allowed and start testing.

If you have any question about the code just ask and i will try my best to reply to you.

> ```
> SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
> SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
> SET !EXTRACT NULL
> TAB T=1
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=form ATTR=CLASS:commentable_item<SP>autoexpand_mode  EXTRACT=HTM
> Set !VAR4 Eval("var exp = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/ id=.(.*?)\" /); exp[1];")
> SET !EXTRACT NULL
> TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:UFIReplyLink
> TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=UL ATTR=CLASS:<SP>UFIReplyList  EXTRACT=HTM
> Set !VAR1 Eval("var exp = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/UFICommentPhotoIcon.(.*?)class/); exp[1];")
> Set !VAR1 Eval("var exp = '{{!VAR1}}'.match(/data-reactid=.(.*?)\"/); exp[1];")
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=i ATTR=data-reactid:{{!VAR1}}
> SET !EXTRACT NULL
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=i ATTR=data-reactid:{{!VAR1}} EXTRACT=HTM
> Set !VAR2 Eval("var exp = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/ id=.(.*?)\"/); exp[1];")
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:{{!VAR4}} ATTR=id:{{!VAR2}} CONTENT=C:\1.jpg
> SET !EXTRACT NULL
> TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=textarea ATTR=title:Write<SP>a<SP>reply... 
> TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=textarea ATTR=title:Write<SP>a<SP>reply... EXTRACT=HTM
> Set !VAR3 Eval("var exp = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/ id=.(.*?)\"/); exp[1];")
> wait seconds=3
> TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=textarea ATTR=title:Write<SP>a<SP>reply... CONTENT=nice
> EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#{{!VAR3}}" KEYS="[13]"
> ```